# caffe convert_imageset pending

Tags: caffe, lmdb, imagenet

When I convert ImageNet dataset to lmdb, convert_imageset will suspend and no longer process image data.Can you tell me how to solve this problem? I have tried it many time.I checked the log.
Every time the number of images that was processed is different.

Comment: Is there anyone encountered this problem? convert_imageset tool is pending when converting a large number of images to lmdb.

Comment: There is no exception,no error, just pending.

Comment: What have you tried so far can you show us some code which helps us to help you.

Comment: I0220 12:42:47.004426 40804 convert_imageset.cpp:147] Processed 2000 files.

Comment: It is pending when convert imageset.The log is no longer printed.

Answer (score 0):

check your image information file (ex. `list.txt`) for correct formatting per line

- every line contains one image file path followed by exactly one space,
- followed by label index (which start from zero) and
- no trailing spaces after label index.

if all above formatting requirements does not hold, `convert_imageset` tool don't behave correctly.

Main points are it requires that *only one space between image file path and label index*, and *no trailing space(s) at end of line*.